# ERR_OKのような表現は何に起因するものでしょうか？

Tags: 命名規則

関数の戻り値などで、正常/異常を返したりします。
その際、用いられる値の定義でよく『ERR_OK』『E_OK』のような表現を見ます。
この『ERR』や『E』は『Error』だと思うのですが、何に起因するものなのでしょうか？

・わざわざ『ERR』や『E』を付ける理由は？『OK』だけではダメな理由は？
・Errorコード定義の集合として分かるようにしているだけ？
・そもそも『Error』では無い？
辺りが気になります。

今まで『まぁ、そういうルールか。』でやっていましたが、久しぶりに遭遇したので質問します。
ご存知の方居られましたら、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

よくある UNIX 系カーネルソースやツールソース、すなわち [c](/questions/tagged/c) の話として

初期の [c](/questions/tagged/c) いわゆる ANSI-C より古いものにおいて `enum` はありませんでした。よってエラーコード一覧のようなものに英単語列を与えるには `#define` しか手はありません。よく知られている通り `#define` はソースコードテキストレベルでの置換で、濫用はご法度です。特に、短い名前を使うのは論外。

```
#define OK 0 /* alice.h */
#define OK 1 /* bob.h */ /* redeclaration */
/* I am charlie, how I can use BOTH `OK` ? */
```

`enum` は [c89](/questions/tagged/c89) で付け加えられたものですが、テキスト置換こそしないまでも、複数の `enum` に同じ名前を与えることはできません。

```
enum resultA { OK=0, ERR=1 };
enum resultB { OK=1, ERR=-1 }; // redeclaration
```

よって [c](/questions/tagged/c) においては [関連性のある複数の名前に] (まあ要するにエラーコード一覧とか) prefix ないし suffix をつけない短い名前を使うと混乱の元です。ないしは作者の違うソースが共存不可能になってしまいます。よってしかたなく prefix / suffix を使うしかなかったってのが実情でしょう。んで `grep` しやすいのは prefix のほうだから

- エラーコードなら `E_` prefix をつけてみた（ライブラリ作者がそうした）
- 既に `E_` prefix が使われちゃっているから仕方なく `ERR_` prefix にしてみた（ライブラリユーザーは）
- 結果コードなら `RESULT_` prefix をつけてみた
- 設定値なら `CONF_` prefix をつけてみた

つまり実装上の都合に過ぎず、海より深い理由は無いとオイラ個人は思っています。

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) では `CallingConvention.StdCall` のように `enum` 名を併記しないといけないようになりましたよね（古くからの [c](/questions/tagged/c) ユーザには「名前が長すぎ」と不評ですが、こちらのほうが絶対にわかりやすくて安全です）

Comment: やはりローカルルールとかで慣例で付けてたprefixがそのまま残ってしまっているんでしょうかね。
なら消せば良いのに...ERROR_OKて意味分からん...と思いますよね？ｗ
回答ありがとうございました。